# ¿Cómo realizar un substring en una variable y compararla?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hola amigos estoy tratando de darle valor a una variable por medio del **substring** de una cadena, pero no sé que estoy haciendo mal. Quizá no está bien implementada mi lógica.

```
declare @x varchar(50);

set @x = (select SUBSTRING ( [IMPORTE (COP)] ,1 , 1 ) FROM #stats_bbva  );

INSERT INTO [dbo].[conciliacionesExcel] ([cuenta], [fechaMov],  [cargo],[saldo], [conceptoBanco])
SELECT '1', [FECHA DE OPERACIÓN], [IMPORTE (COP)], [SALDO (COP)], [OBSERVACIONES] FROM #stats_bbva 
where @x  LIKE '%-%';

INSERT INTO [dbo].[conciliacionesExcel] ([cuenta], [fechaMov],  [abono],[saldo], [conceptoBanco])
SELECT '1', [FECHA DE OPERACIÓN], [IMPORTE (COP)], [SALDO (COP)], [OBSERVACIONES] FROM #stats_bbva 

DELETE TOP (1) FROM #stats_bbva
```

En si estoy buscando saber si  **[IMPORTE (COP)]** contiene el simbolo **"-"** y así poder acomodarlo en la columna que quiero.

Este es mi error al correrlo:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 25
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: lo unico que me parece raro en el query es que no existen los valores del insert...

Comment: Hola fran @FranciscoAcevedo es como mi pregunta de ayer, pero en este formato tengo la cantidad y el simbolo variable en la misma celda :s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu problema es este:

```
set @x = (select SUBSTRING ( [IMPORTE (COP)] ,1 , 1 ) FROM #stats_bbva  );
```

Tu subconsulta está retornando más de una fila, esto en un `SET` es inválido. ¿Por qué? por que un `SET` asigna una variable escalar, es decir solo un único valor, y lo que estás haciendo es asignar `[IMPORTE (COP)]` pero de múltiples filas. Esto podría tener sentido si hicieras un `TOP 1` para asegurar un único valor, pero sin duda eso no es lo que necesitas en este caso.

El filtro lo debes resolver desde la consulta:

```
SELECT '1', 
       [FECHA DE OPERACIÓN], 
       [IMPORTE (COP)], 
       [SALDO (COP)], 
       [OBSERVACIONES] 
       FROM #stats_bbva 
       where SUBSTRING ( [IMPORTE (COP)] ,1 , 1 ) = '-';
```

- Nota que el substring lo aplico directamente en el `where` sobre la columna que corresponde
- No uso el `like` ya que no tiene sentido, si recortas un solo carácter, lo único que hace falta es compararlo con `-`